Supabase with Deno backend not serving functions
I am trying to host a Supabase backend on my local machine. It is partially working--if I click on the studio link for example, I can access the studio and everything appears to be functional.
However, when I run supabase functions serve and try to access any of the functions via my browser or Postman, I am unable to. On the Postman and browser side of things I get "Function not found." On the backend, I get "error in main worker connection: error writing a body to connection." My functions appear to be being served, as shown by the log "Serving functions on http://127.0.0.1:54321/functions/v1/," but I cannot access any of them in any way. I also checked that the port is not in an excluded range, and some other potential fixes I saw recommended to others online or by ChatGPT.
Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!
